# Properly link two C# WCF services against each other

Tags: c#, wcf, service

Is there a clean way to link two WCF Services agains each other? I need one service to send request to another, that will asynchronously reply in time.

When I add a service reference to one project, I need other one to be compiled and running. 
But it can't be running because it needs to be referenced to the first one.

So it's a vicious circle :(

Comment: so you are creating a circular dependency by referencing each service in the other service?

Comment: yep, that's what it is

Comment: I hope this is only for an experiment

Comment: You could put the service contracts (interfaces) in a separate assembly and then have both services reference that assembly - this would remove the circular reference issue.  But I think long-term you'd be better served to reexamine how you're architecting things so you can remove the circular reference issue.